# Prime numbers calculator takes too much time (JAVA)

Tags: java, primes

When I run this code to find sum of prime numbers below 20 it works fine, but when try to find sum below 2500000 it takes too much time. It's been at least 20 minutes and it's still running. It seems like it's not working. How do I fix it?

```
class PrimeSummation {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int sum = 0;
        for(int i = 1; i < 2500000; i++) {
            int count = 0;
            for(int j = 1; j < i + 1; j++) {
                if((i%j) == 0) {
                    count++;
                }
            }
            if(count == 2) {
                sum += i;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your second for loop doesn't have to go all the way to i+1, i/2 is enough.

Comment: Well your algorithm to find prime numbers is not very efficient. Try implementing the Sieve of Eratosthenes.

Comment: You have so many iterations (about `2500000^2`). In the first case it's only `400`

Comment: You also can't use `int` for the answer as it overflows. Writing a method to efficiently add up all the prime numbers under `2500000` is really hard. I'd search SO for similar questions.

Comment: You could keep that algorithm and change the hardware. Try forking it across 2500000 processors or consider using a theoretical quantum computer.

Comment: @SkinnyJ For a quantum computer, that you should probably use Shor's algorithm.

Comment: @ILikeTau good point!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sum` cannot be an `int` because the answer is `219697708195` whereas `Integer.MAX_VALUE` is only `2147483647`. You must use a `long` or a `BigInteger` instead.

Your algorithm is very slow, because for every one of the `2500000` numbers you are starting from scratch to decide whether it is prime or not, and your approach for testing whether a number is prime (try every possible factor) is not very efficient.

The following code produces the answer in about a tenth of a second on my machine.

```
int num = 2500000;
long sum = 0;
boolean[] arr = new boolean[num];
for (int p = 2; p < num; p++) {
    if (!arr[p]) {
        sum += p;
        for (int k = p * 2; k < num; k += p)
            arr[k] = true;
    }
}
System.out.println(sum);
```

Answer (score 3):

Keeping track of previously found primes seems to help:

```
    BigInteger sum = BigInteger.ZERO;
    List<Integer> primes = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i = 2; i < 2500000; i++) {
        boolean isPrime = true;
        for(int j = 0; j < primes.size() && primes.get(j)<= Math.sqrt(i); j++) {
            int p = primes.get(j);
            if((i%p) == 0) {
                isPrime=false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(isPrime) {
            sum = sum.add(BigInteger.valueOf(i));
            primes.add(i);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
```

Came up with answer:

219697708195

Comment: :) __________________

Answer (score 1):

If you want better performance for generating a large number `prime number`, you should use `Sieve formula`.

You can Learn [Sieve_of_Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) formula for prime number generation.

According to [Sieve_of_Eratosthenes](http://en.literateprograms.org/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes_%28C_Plus_Plus%29):

```
import java.util.*;

public class Sieve
{
    private BitSet sieve;

    private Sieve() {}

    private Sieve(int size) {
        sieve = new BitSet((size+1)/2);
    }

    private boolean is_composite(int k)
    {
        assert k >= 3 && (k % 2) == 1;
        return sieve.get((k-3)/2);
    }

    private void set_composite(int k)
    {
        assert k >= 3 && (k % 2) == 1;
        sieve.set((k-3)/2);
    }

    public static List<Integer> sieve_of_eratosthenes(int max)
    {
        Sieve sieve = new Sieve(max + 1); // +1 to include max itself
        for (int i = 3; i*i <= max; i += 2) {
            if (sieve.is_composite(i))
                continue;

            // We increment by 2*i to skip even multiples of i
            for (int multiple_i = i*i; multiple_i <= max; multiple_i += 2*i)
                sieve.set_composite(multiple_i);

        }
        List<Integer> primes = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        primes.add(2);
        for (int i = 3; i <= max; i += 2)
            if (!sieve.is_composite(i))
                primes.add(i);

        return primes;
    }
}
```

Performance:

[image]

Comment: cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms#Empirical_orders_of_growth. you'll see marked change for the worse from 1M up, in your data - probably because of cache issues. segmented sieve might provide an improvement for that.